AMC 10 Math Question Using Algebraic Manipulation

What is the greatest integer less than or equal to $\frac{3^{100} + 2^{100}}{3^{96} + 2^{96}}?$
$({\rm A}) \, 80 \qquad ({\rm B}) \, 81 \qquad ({\rm C}) \, 96 \qquad ({\rm D}) \, 97 \qquad ({\rm E}) \, 625$

I don't know where to start with this. I tried to factor it but it has even exponents so I cant do that... What do I do?

@RupertRybka :  Seems to be from 2018 (or earlier): https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2018_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_14

Hint: try to bound this expression by $2$ consequtive numbers, one from above and the other from below

Hint bis : You can hit the expression with modulo $80$ eg or others.

Long division works.

Just so you know - you are expected to show your attempts for questions you post here. If you tried something, show us so we can guide our answer.

\begin{align*}
2^4 &< 3^4  \\
2^{100} &< 2^{96}3^4  \\
3^{100} + 2^{100} &< 3^{100} + 2^{96}3^4  \\
\frac{3^{100} + 2^{100}}{3^{96} + 2^{96}} &< \frac{3^{96}3^4 + 2^{96}3^4}{3^{96} + 2^{96}} = 3^{4} \cdot1 = 81. \\
\end{align*}
So, of the given options, it must be $80$.
(If this is a "show your work" problem, I'd accept the last line of the display as sufficient justification to select "$80$".)

This answer is so clever I love it

HINT.- Clearly $$\dfrac{3^{100}+2^{100}}{3^{96}+2^{96}}=\dfrac{81\times3^{96}+16\times2^{96}}{3^{96}+2^{96}}=\dfrac{65a^{96}}{a^{96}+b^{96}}+16=\dfrac{65}{1+(\frac{b}{a})^{96}}+16$$
so, since the denominator is always positive, the desired number is $65+16=81$

I note that the given expression is $80.999,999,999,999,999,1{\dots}$; the greatest integer less or equal to the given number is $80$...

In fact, "since the denominator is always" greater than $1$, the desired number is strictly upper bounded by $81$, so is at most $80$...

@Eric Towers: You are right. Thanks. Anyway I wanted to give another  answer and it is reached excepting the  hasty conclusion. Regards.
